# how to update angularjs view after change database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I've got simple ngResource factory:

```
function User($resource) {
  return $resource("http://localhost:8080/api/users", {id: "@_id"}, {
    update: {
      method: "PUT"
    }
  });
}
```

That give me a pretty nice CRUD actions. But the problem is when I change /api data by sending PUT/POST/DELETE request my view doesn't automatically refreshed. 
I need manually update page to see my changes. I try to use `$apply`(throws $digest allready in progress) or put `$scope.users = User.query()` in callback function(flashesh the page, looks like automatically refresh the 'users' array).

To make request to the server I'm using ngClick directive. For example:

VIEW.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
  <td>
    {{user.name}}
  </td>
  <td>
    <a ng-click="save(user)">SAVE</a>
  </td>
```

CONTROLLER.js

```
$scope.users = User.query();

$scope.save = function (user) {
  user.$update();
}
```

NODE.js + Mongodb

```
router.put("/", function (req, res, next) {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, req.body, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.json(user);
  });
});
```

P.S.

I dont think, that `splice` or `push` methods with `$scope.users` is the correct way to do Angularjs CRUD applications at all

Answer (score 0):

well, the solution is add option `{new: true}` in `findBy`-mongoose method:

```
router.put("/", function (req, res, next) { 
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, req.body, {new: true}, 
    function (err, user) {
      if (err) return next(err); 
      return res.json(user); 
  }); 
});
```